# Can't get access to firestore local emulator suite in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-tools

I am not able to connect to Firestore emulator in Flutter. It is reflecting in the main Firebase console.
I'm using android emulator

```
void initState() {
super.initState();
firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
firestore.settings = Settings(
  host: '10.0.2.2:8080',
  sslEnabled: false,
);

firestore.collection('tokens').add({'data': 16});
}
```

I configured the emulator according to the documentation.

```
─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ ✔  All emulators ready! It is now safe to connect your app │
│ i  View Emulator UI at http://localhost:4000                │
└─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

┌───────────┬────────────────┬─────────────────────────────────┐
│ Emulator  │ Host:Port      │ View in Emulator UI             │
├───────────┼────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────┤
│ Functions │ localhost:5001 │ http://localhost:4000/functions │
├───────────┼────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────┤
│ Firestore │ localhost:8080 │ http://localhost:4000/firestore │
└───────────┴────────────────┴─────────────────────────────────┘
  Emulator Hub running at localhost:4400
  Other reserved ports: 4500

Issues? Report them at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues and attach the *-debug.log files.

!  It looks like you're trying to access functions.config().functions but there is no value there. You can learn more about setting up config here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator
```

The firebase version :

```
firebase --version 
9.11.0
```

firebase.json

```
 {
  "emulators": {
    "functions": {
      "port": 5001
    },
    "ui": {
      "enabled": true
    },
    "firestore": {
      "port": 8080
    }
  }
}
```

There is no data showing up on http://localhost:4000/firestore and the data is reflecting on the main firebase console even after changing the settings(host).

I get this error sometimes :

> MissingPluginException (MissingPluginException(No implementation found
> for method DocumentReference#set on channel
> plugins.flutter.io/firebase_firestore))

pubspec.yaml

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
cupertino_icons: ^1.0.1
  firebase_auth: ^0.20.1
  equatable: ^1.2.6
  bloc: ^6.1.3
  flutter_bloc: ^6.1.3
  firebase_core: ^0.7.0
  cloud_firestore: ^0.16.0
  google_sign_in: "^4.5.1"
  flutter_rating_bar: ^4.0.0
  image_picker: ^0.6.7+17
  firebase_storage: ^7.0.0
  syncfusion_flutter_calendar: ^18.4.42
  simple_time_range_picker: ^0.0.2
  firebase_messaging: ^8.0.0-dev.15
  cloud_functions: ^0.9.0
```

Would really appreciate some help. Thank you

Comment: Couple of silly questions that I nonetheless feel the need to ask: Have you tried connecting using the IP instead of the "localhost" tag? Are you using the Functions you've enabled at all? If so, have you [enabled clear text communication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator#instrument_your_app_for_callable_functions#:~:text=Android%20only.)? And lastly, have you added the data that you're expecting to see? Firestore emulator is an emulator after all, so it will not have your production data, as it's intended for a development environment, not a production environment.

Comment: Yes, I have tried using IP. I have tried adding data to it. Of course sir, It will not have the production data. Using Android 10, so no issue of enabling clear text communication.

Comment: Sorry, I only just realized, you're using base Firebase with Flutter instead of Flutterfire? I had almost completely forgotten about [FirebaseExtended](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended), so I didn't really consider it. But yeah, Flutter has a distro that incorporates Firebase a little better, you still require the emulator. Though, if [this article](https://fireship.io/snippets/firestore-emulator-flutter/) is to be believed, you've set up the initialization correctly... Sorry I didn't notice the `data.add()` before. I would recommend trying Flutterfire over Flutter, should help with impl...

Comment: Implementation, is what I was gonna end that comment with. But character limits are a thing

Comment: No problem. But I am using FlutterFire.

Comment: Hmm... I'm guessing you've also tried cleaning and getting the packages again. (Pardon the small followups, everything you've shown I believe is correct, so I'm trying to dig deeper to try and see if there's any obscure little nuance that might be causing your issues)

Comment: Oh, followup question: would you mind showing us your dependencies? Might be something funky or an update missing there.

Comment: I appreciate you following up so rapidly. I haven't updated my dependencies as I have not upgraded to null safety yet. I have added the dependencies above.

Answer (score 0):

The problem for me was that the production data was still in the cache of my app. After reinstalling it worked!

Answer (score -1):

You will need to use the latest version of your dependencies. You can check the latest version [here](https://pub.dev/packages).

After updating your dependencies you will have to run:

```
flutter clean
flutter packages get
```